# python executing both if and else statement together

Tags: python, if-statement

I am not sure why, but python is executing the if statement then the else statement in the same iteration

i'm cutting out unimportant code:

```
from livewires import games
...
...
def update(self):
  if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_s):
    if self.y == games.screen.height/3:
      self.y = games.screen.height/2
    else:
      self.y = games.screen.height
```

In my mind it should go:
if 's' is pressed:
then, if the height is equal to whatever do whatever
otherwise, do whatever2

But the computer is going:
if 's' is pressed
then, make the height equal to whatever and since the height is no longer equal to whatever, make it equal to whatever2

I have tried this by using single if statements with 'and' operators and all kinds of funky ways of doing it, but everything I do, the code just seems to move to the next line regardless of if/elif/else

I even tried implementing a sort of timer that kind of works, but is unreliable.

Comment: it's not possible. What is possible is that `update` is called many times,..

Comment: Use 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' and then step through each part to check what the computer is actually doing

Comment: It works just fine with the trace. I think it is just moving too fast. Like a press and lift of the s-key takes much more time than "computer time", so-to-speak, and it runs the update twice (or more if I add more statements)
I figured that, that is why I put the time in at one point in time, but even that had similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a pretty easy fix. I added a timer in the **init** and added this:

```
def update(self):
  self.timer -= 1
  if self.timer == 0:
    self.timer = 8
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_s):
      if self.y == games.screen.height/3:
        self.y = games.screen.height/2
      else:
        self.y = games.screen.height
```

It took the pdb.set_trace() to figure out it did, in fact, execute both individually (just really fast). It moved so fast it looked like it did both simultaneously.